# Losing all variable labels when mutating a column

Tags: r, mutated, r-labelled

I uploaded an .sav file using haven.

```
df <- read_sav("file.sav", user_na = FALSE)
```

This makes sure that all the metadata including the labels are imported into r.

However, after running all my code (mutations etc.), I notice that all variables that had some kind of mutation have lost all the metadata. How can I make sure it doesn't get lost?

For example after doing this:

```
df <- df %>%
    mutate(col1 = gsub('\\s+', '', toupper(col1)))
```

col1 would no longer have labels from library(labelled)
It happens after any kind of mutation.

Comment: A replication of what's happening could help with understanding your problem. It's not clear how you imported the file.

Comment: @Pedro I added more info. Since it happens with any mutation, I assume it is a general enough issue to not need a dataset.